# Why am I getting an error when connecting to telnet?

Tags: python, telnet, telnetlib

So whenever I run my script I end up getting this error:

```
2020-03-12T17:59:51 8100.701 ERR IOException in ReadLine for TelnetClient_127.0.0.1:55356: Unable to 
write data to the transport connection: An established connection was aborted by the software in your 
host machine.
.
SocketException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine.

2020-03-12T17:59:51 8100.727 ERR Exception in thread TelnetClient_127.0.0.1:55356:
InvalidOperationException: The operation is not allowed on non-connected sockets.
```

But even though it says the connection was aborted, it still lets me execute commands afterward.

Here is the code I'm using to connect to the telnet, please let me know if there's anything extra that I need to include

```
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read(Path(".../telnetconfig.xml"))
HOST = config.get("telnet", "telnet_host")
PORT = config.get("telnet", "telnet_port")
PASS = config.get("telnet", "telnet_pass")

tn = telnetlib.Telnet(HOST, PORT)
tn.read_until(b"Please enter password:")
tn.write(PASS.encode('ascii') + b"\r\n")
```

Comment: It's not letting you execute commands, the second error comes from trying to send commands on a disconnected connection.

Comment: it might be giving me an error for sending commands but for some reason the commands  still go through and it gives me the correct output